# "Cleaning area" or "cleaning surface"?

Tags: word-usage

Question:

The English term for:

> the total area of a building/floor in m2/Sq Ft that needs to be cleaned

Is that called the "Cleaning surface", or the "Cleaning area"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't actually use either phrase - "cleaning surface" sounds like the surface itself is doing the cleaning ("The new X-9000 floor-washing machine has a huge **cleaning surface**, so you'll finish in half the time!"), while "cleaning area" sounds like the place where cleaning is happening ("Next on our tour of the fish-packing plant is the **cleaning area**!")

I would use "area", since you want to convey a measurement, but I would say "**the area to be cleaned**."  Trying to make it shorter than that is likely to lead to confusion.

Comment: What about "cleaning space"?

Comment: I would avoid it too, for the same reason as "cleaning area."  For some reason, **cleaning** as an adjective has an active, rather than passive, connotation.

Comment: OP might consider also "area that needs cleaning", "area in need of cleaning" and of course [sic] "tbc area" (where *tbc* means *to-be-cleaned*)

Comment: All of those would be good replacements too.  I don't know whether I'd introduce a new abbreviation for one-time use, though, especially since it would have to be explained (as you just have.)  If this phrase were going to be used over and over and over, then I would introduce "**tbc**" ("to be cleaned") once, and then simply substitute _tbc_ from then on.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest calling it the **cleanable area**

Comment: there is a difference between "cleanable area" and "(total) area that needs cleaning"; "cleanable area" is theoretical maximum of the later term.